# Unsure on how to convert the code I already have to html dom

Tags: php, dom

The scraping code I already have is not working so i've searched and found that I need to use DOM and I am unsure how to implement what I already have to DOM even after reading. I am worried about breaking something. Any help/tutorials is highly appreciated.

```
// get input
$link = post('link1');
$category = post('category');
$time = post('time');

// markers
$findme1 = 'https://www.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=';
$findme2 = '<span class="reward">';
$findme3 = '</span>';

// check if link is correct
$rightlink = strpos($link, $findme1);
// if link is correct
  if ($rightlink !== false)
{
    // get html from link
    $html = file($link);

    // iterate through html
    foreach ($html as $i => $line)
    {
        // set title
        if($i == 640) $title = htmlentities($line);

        // set requester
        if($i==669) $requester = htmlentities($line);

        if($i==678)
        {
            // modify the line and save as reward
            $line_modified = str_replace($findme2, '', $line);
            $line_modified = str_replace($findme3, '', $line_modified);
            $reward = htmlentities($line_modified);
        }

        // set qualifications
        if($i==711) $q = htmlentities($line);
    }
```

Comment: "I am worried about breaking something" --- this is what you're paid for. If you worry to try, then why do we need to bother?

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), it'll make your life easy, read the documentation and do whatever you want to do. If you are familiar with `jQuery` then it's already in your grip. Look at the example given below

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://requester.mturk.com/');
foreach($html->find('a') as $link){
    echo $link . '<br />';
}
```

That code fetches all data from the `https://requester.mturk.com` and prints all links using `foreach` loop. the code is self descriptive I think.